# SQL Server built-in function Stdevp calculating incorrectly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, floating-point-precision

I am using SQL Server 2008, one of my requirements is to calculate population standard deviation. SQL Server provides a built-in function `stdevp` for the same. I am using it but I am befuddled by the result I am getting. Population standard deviation for a group of same numbers should be zero but here I get some different although minuscule value.

```
drop table guest.tempTable;

create table guest.tempTable (column1 varchar , column2 decimal(10,6))

insert into guest.tempTable values('a',3578.2700);
insert into guest.tempTable values('a',3578.2700);
insert into guest.tempTable values('a',3578.2700);        
insert into guest.tempTable values('a',3578.2700);

insert into guest.tempTable values('a',3578.2700);
commit;
```

The following is the stdevp query:

```
select stdevp(column2) from guest.tempTable
group by column1
```

The result that I get is

```
------------------------ 
5.459150335692846E-5
```

which should have been 0.00.

The documentation for `stdevp` says that it returns a float. So I am guessing this must be a rounding off issue, but I am unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Floating point numbers are not 100% accurate.**

> The fact that floating-point numbers cannot precisely represent all
>   real numbers, and that floating-point operations cannot precisely
>   represent true arithmetic operations, leads to many surprising
>   situations. This is related to the finite precision with which
>   computers generally represent numbers.
>
> For example, the non-representability of 0.1 and 0.01 (in binary)
>   means that the result of attempting to square 0.1 is neither 0.01 nor
>   the representable number closest to it. In 24-bit (single precision)
>   representation, 0.1 (decimal) was given previously as e = −4; s =
>   110011001100110011001101, which is
>
> ```
> 0.100000001490116119384765625 exactly.
> ```
>
> Squaring this number gives
>
> ```
> 0.010000000298023226097399174250313080847263336181640625 exactly.
> ```
>
> Squaring it with single-precision floating-point hardware (with
>   rounding) gives
>
> ```
> 0.010000000707805156707763671875 exactly.
> ```
>
> But the representable number closest to 0.01 is
>
> ```
> 0.009999999776482582092285156250 exactly.
> ```

---

You can read about it [HERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes this is a rounding off issue, but I was hoping if there was any solution anybody knew which would get the correct result, like if I change the precision of the said field(or the datatype itself) but I guess it would still be going through the same floating point arithmetic :(.

Comment: One possible solution might be to do it without float. Use decimal or numeric.

Comment: I tried to use other data types but with no success, I am now relying on calculating stdev in the application layer instead of calculating it in the database layer, then I am rounding it off to a acceptable limit. Somehow stdev in java yeilds comparatively precise results (although they wont be still 0) as compared to SQLServer, hence I am taking this approach.